# Ctrl Alt Numpad 0 keeps moving my object?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Trying to follow along with a tutorial and in that tutorial the idea is to look at an object I created from the front and then set the camera to the current view.

The steps to do this are:

1. <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> (Front perspective)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> (Align Camera to View)

For some reason whenever I do this I don't see anything in the camera and then panning the view around I see that my object seems to have moved to where I wanted the camera and my camera hasn't moved at all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer was to first select the camera and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> and then perform the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

User CD38 on http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-78116.html explains:

> I'm pretty sure you made the body into the camera at some point with
>   an accidental Ctrl-zero when it was selected. You need to be careful
>   with those Numpad-zero commands. Here they are:
>
> - zero alone: changes the viewport so you're looking
>     through the active camera. ("I wonder what the camera's seeing?")
> - Ctrl-alt-zero: moves the camera to match the current 3D
>     viewport. ("I like this angle; let's put the camera here.")
>     This is why your humanoid is jumping around and looking
>     inside itself. Very mind-bending.
> - Ctrl-zero : makes the selected object into the active
>     camera. Anything can be a "camera." In this case it's your
>     humanoid object. This is poorly documented and seems to cause
>     all kinds of grief because it's an easy misstep.
>
> Select the real camera with the RMB and do Ctrl-zero and all should be
>   well.

(I found this answer and decided to document it here on stackexchange because I had a hard time finding the answer and would have expected this question and answer on this site)

Comment: Speaking of non-documented, Googling "blender **move view to camera**" gave me no relevant results. I didn't realize there was a plain `NumZero` until I ran into this question by chance. This saves me so much time setting up cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you want to switch to an different camera during your animation go to the frame number when you want to switch from camera. Select/activate the camera where you want to switch to and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> .